# Regex for all section headers (2.0, 2.1.2, 2.3.1.5, etc)

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been using something like this

```
/(\w[.]\w)+/ig
```

Which isn't quite doing what I need to. I'm trying to match to any period with a digit before AND after, no matter the length. Must match at least once.

Is there a way to do this in one line?

Thank you all

Full answer:

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d+)+$/gm
```

Thanks everyone! You're all wizards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want a regex like below.

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d+)*$/m
```

`(?:\.\d+)*` repeats the decimal part zero or more times. So the above regex would match the number formats like `9`, `9.9` , `9.9.9` or `9.99`

Comment: You guys on here are wizards.

Comment: That matches the pattern, the full answer to the question would be with the global and multi-line flags like `/^\d+(?:\.\d+)*$/gm`

Comment: @nzondlo g flag is unnecessary. `m` would be fine.

Comment: and this actually matches numbers regardless if there is a following section  attached. `54` for example, matches. So I guess I would need the non-capturing group to match AT LEAST once? Edit: `+` instead of `*` finds it. Thank you

Comment: then change the `*` to `+`, if you want a dot to be present. `/^\d+(?:\.\d+)+$/m`. `*` repeats the previous token zero or more times where `+` repeats the previous token one or more times.

Answer (score 1):

That would be `/(\d+(?:\.\d+))*/g`

Explaining:

- `\d+` mandatory first few digits
- `(?:  )*` followed by a non capturing group that can repeat 0 or more times
- `\.\d+` with a dot followed by one or more digits inside.

If you *require* at least one more section (`N` is not valid, but `N.M` is), change the `*` on the non capturing group to `+` (`0 or more` to `1 or more`).

Comment: You have an extra open parenthesis (or missing closing one).

Comment: I did need the non-capturing group to match at least once. `+` instead of `*` does do it. Thank you!